# Pythonnet - how to easily convert python object to c# object and vice versa

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I'm using `pythonnet` package to use C# binaries in Python. I'm wondering what is the easiest way to convert a NET dcitionary/list/object to Python dictionary/list/object. The reason is that:

a) To run C# funtion I need to create C# arguments. So if the function takes as an argument a list, then I have to do the following:

```
netList = List[String]()
netList.Add("ABC")
```

i.e I have to create C# List with specifying the type of arguments. Similarly I can't pass `123`, I have to pass `Double(123)`. Is there a way to convert Ptyhon object automatically to appropriate C# objects?

b) If I run the C# function, then the results is also the C# object so I have to convert C# dictoanry\list to Python dictionary\list. Is there a dedicated function for that?

Answer (score 0):

I've used these two `Python` functions to help me get passed a similar problem. Maybe that can help you to.

```
    def PythonToCSharp2Darray(input_list: list, array_depth: tuple = (4, 4)) -> Array:
        """Convert a python N-List to a C# Array."""
        CSharpArray = Array.CreateInstance(Double, array_depth[0], array_depth[1])
        for i in range(array_depth[0]):
            for j in range(array_depth[1]):
                CSharpArray.SetValue(input_list[i][j], i, j)
        return CSharpArray
```

```
    def CSharpToPython2Darray(input_array: Array, array_depth: tuple = (4, 4)) -> list:
        """Convert a C# Array to a N-List."""
        PythonList = []
        PythonList.append([])
        for i in range(array_depth[0]):
            for j in range(array_depth[1]):
                PythonList[i].append(input_array.GetValue(i, j))
            PythonList.append([])
        return PythonList
```

Please note that the 'list' and 'array' are `Python` types and the 'List' and 'Array' are `C#` types, which are included via:

```
    import System  # #                                   Import the .NET library into Python environment
    from System import Object, String, Array, Double  # #Import the .NET library into Python environment
    from System.Collections.Generic import List  # #     Import the .NET library into Python environment
```